# Recommended Books for Verbal Arithmetic Expressions on "plus, minus, divided by, multiplied by"

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I am from Vietnam and have just transferred to Australia. And I have a lot of trouble with understanding the way people use "verbal expressions on mathematics operations (addition, subtraction,...). I am in advanced math; it's not a problem with doing math but a problem with vocabulary.

It's familiar when they say :"1 plus 1 equals 2" to express 1+1=2. But then sometimes I heard they said :"1 increased by 1 equals 2". Or when they use the phrase "one subtracted by one is zero", "subtracted from" instead of "minus". It's just that I hardly fully understand what my teacher say and I am very afraid to misunderstand or miss something in the future. Furthermore, I have been looking in the dictionary and some words that is not even has the structure as what my teacher write such as "4 subtracted by 2 equals 2"

Could anyone recommend a Internet source or a book on this topic (with examples of using the words) ?

Comment: I don't think any source will help you with such ridiculous usage as "4 subtracted by 2". Did a teacher actually say that?

Comment: Yes, the full explanation was :"If we divide 4 by 2, we get 2. In subtraction, we can use this phrase to express 4-2=2 by saying subtract 4 by 2 or 4 minus 2" This was one I was in my homeland. He came from Philippines. But the important thing is that I still use "4 minus 2" because I don't know any resource verify "4 subtracted by 2"

Comment: I just need a name of a book that teach this matter (reliable sources textbook) because I am not a native English speaker, I don't know which is wrong or correct (though I am fully comprehend the words).

Comment: The Macquarie Dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to think of an easy reference for this. It is a real problem if the language is a barrier. Some expressions like "4 subtracted by 2" doesn't make sense regardless of the type of English, because you subtract something *from* something else, not *by* something. You do *divide by* though. You may just have to commit to memory the various ways locals express mathematics in verse form.